# In Outlook, how to display full address, not contact name, in "To" field?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I'm using Outlook in Chrome browser.  Problem with what is displayed in the new message "To"  field. Example: I have a contact "John Doe" saved with two email addresses, "JohnD@server1.com" and "JDoe@server2.com".  If I enter "John Doe" in "To" I want to know which email address, (or both?) are being actually used by Outlook to send the message to. But all that is displayed in "To" is "John Doe".  Even if I enter in "To", one of his full addresses literally, for example "JohnD@server1.com", than "To" will still show only "John Doe" so I don't know which of the addresses in Contacts are being used.

Is there a way to tell Outlook to display actual email addresses in "To", at all times? I remember some older email app or website that would show the name of the contact followed by the email address.  If you had entered both addresses literally, "To" would display "John Doe [JD@server2.com], John Doe [JDoe@server2.com]"  This format would be much better, IMHO.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: There is a display option in Desktop Outlook to show the complete name.  Do you see such option in Outlook Web Mail?

Answer (score 0):

There are some possible ways to show the full email address of the sender and the recipient in the To and From fields of Outlook messages. Here are some of them:

You can add a custom column called “Sender’s Email Address” by using a formula in the View Settings. This will display the sender’s full email address in the mailing list.
You can right-click on the column row in your Inbox and choose “Field Chooser”. Then scroll down and choose “Forms” and select “Personal Forms”. Here you can add the “Sender Email Address” field to your column headings. This will show the email address followed by the display name of the sender.

However, these methods may not work for internal (Exchange) messages, as Outlook does not need email addresses to send emails internally. Also, some of these settings may be controlled by your Exchange administrator. And， there is currently no option available to change this display in the Outlook desktop client or from the perspective of an Exchange or Office 365 administrator. Based on my search，@Faery Fu-MSFT in this thread has already provided feedback, and you can also vote for it in order to get this feature faster. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1314378/how-to-display-full-email-address-in-the-to-field

Comment: These suggestions do not affect the Editor fields (like for a new email)

Comment: I am writing to see how everything is going on with this thread. Is there any update on this case?